# Exercise 7, Section 5.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, determinant

> Let $K$ be a commutative ring with identity. Show that the determinant function on $2 \times 2$ matrices $A$ over $K$ is alternating and $2$-linear as a function of the columns of $A$.

“As a function of columns of $A$” I assume it means we replace rows with columns in definition of alternative and $2$-linear.

**My attempt:** Let $A$ $=\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \\ \end{bmatrix}$ $=[\alpha \text{ }\beta]\in M_2(K)$; $\alpha$, $\beta$ are columns of $A$. Fix first column. Let $c\in K$ and $\gamma$ be a column. Then $D([\alpha \text{ }\text{ }c\cdot \beta +\gamma])$ $=D(\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & c A_{12}+A_{12}^\prime\\ A_{21} & c A_{22}+A_{22}^\prime \end{bmatrix})$ $=A_{11}\cdot (c A_{22}+A_{22}^\prime)$ $-$ $A_{21}\cdot (c A_{12}+A_{12}^\prime A_{21})$ $=c\cdot A_{11}A_{22}-c\cdot A_{21}A_{12}$ $+$ $A_{11}A_{22}^\prime -A_{21}A_{12}^\prime$ $=c\cdot (A_{11}A_{22}-A_{21}A_{12})$ $+$ $(A_{11}A_{22}^\prime -A_{21}A_{12}^\prime)$ $=c\cdot D([\alpha\text{ }\beta])+D([\alpha \text{ }\gamma])$. Similarly $D([c\cdot \alpha +\gamma \text{ }\text{ }\beta])$ $=c\cdot D([\alpha \text{ }\beta])+D([\gamma \text{ }\beta])$. Hence $D:M_2(K)\to K$ is $2$-linear as a function of column of $A$.

Let $B$ $=\begin{bmatrix} B_{11} & B_{11} \\ B_{21} & B_{21} \\ \end{bmatrix}$ $=[\beta \text{ }\beta]\in M_2(K)$; $\beta$ is column of $B$. Then $D(B)$ $=B_{11}B_{21}-B_{11}B_{21}$ $=0$. Let $A^\prime$ $= \begin{bmatrix} A_{12} & A_{11} \\ A_{22} & A_{21} \\ \end{bmatrix}$ $=[\beta \text{ }\alpha]$. Then $D(A^\prime)$ $=A_{12}A_{21}-A_{11}A_{22}$ $=-D(A)$. Hence $D$ is alternative. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: Yes apart from a minor typo. Note once you've proven it is multilinear in the columns and zero when the columns are equal you don't need to prove that it changes sign when the columns are interchanged, you get that for free.

Comment: @blargoner yes you’re right. There is a general result, $D(A)=0$, when two rows of A are equal$\implies$$D(A^\prime)=-D(A)$. Hoffman’s used both statements in definition of alternative function saying “as matter of convenience”.